# How to move an input cell to another sheet without rewriting all the formulas linked to it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I feel I should know this, but I don't :(

Using Excel 2016. Say I have a cell which is the input to many formulas. If I want to move it to another location in the same sheet, I can just drag it, and all the formulas will update - I don't need to re-enter them or change them.

**But what if I want to move that input to another sheet? Can I do that without having to re-enter all the formulas?**
The "lazy" way to do it would be to leave the input where it is, create another sheet, write the input there, and link the "old" input to the "new one", so that the formulas read the old input, which in turn is set = to the new one in the other tab. But is there a more elegant way, that gets rid of the "old input" altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While dragging the cell, hold down the Alt key and drag it onto the sheet tab of the desired sheet. The sheet will activate and you can drag/release the cell in the desired location. The references will update.

Instead of dragging, you can also Cut the cell via the ribbon command, context menu or with Ctrl+X and then paste into another sheet.